# Ruby on Rails - How to find/manipulate DOM elements

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dom, erb

I started learning Rub/Rails about a month ago, but haven't been able to find many resources specific to my issue.
I understand that in HTML/JS you can do something like:

```
let elements = document.getElementByName('name')
```

1. Is there a way in rails to get elements that share the class/id/name?
2. How can we interact with those elements? for example: if a div with a specific name already exists, append some data from our rails application to that div instead of creating a new one.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In Ruby? What *specifically* are you trying to do? Ruby/Rails runs on the server side--unless you're scraping a site this isn't really a thing. JS is what runs in the browser.

Comment: Specifically in Rails, for example say in an index.html.erb file I have:

<% @events.each do |event| %>
<div name=<%=event.date %>

If possible, I want to create an if/els statement that checks if a div with the same name has already has been created. If true, add that information to it.  If not, create a new div with name equal to the date.

Comment: Why can't you just use [`dom_id`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RecordIdentifier.html#method-i-dom_id) to generate the dom id? That should make sure that you do not generate the same "name" twice unless you render the same event twice on the same page.

Comment: This is almost certainly an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm really missing the point, what you're asking for isn't possible.

DOM manipulation (using Javascript) is something that happens client-side, in the browser; the browser requests a page, the server responds with an HTML document, and then the browser builds the DOM and we go from there, running Javascript, and potentially inspecting and manipulating the DOM.

Ruby on Rails is server-side; in the above description, it would be involved in the "the server responds" step, but there is no DOM at that point; it's simply generating an HTML document, using models / a view / a controller.

Comment: with respect to your explanation above, OP: it sounds like what you should do is perform that kind of logical manipulation in the controller so that you end up with e.g. @event_dates each of which contains 1 or more events; then pass that to the view for rendering. Point of terminology: that's not DOM manipulation, though, because there is no DOM until it's got to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation everyone, I get it now! 
I think you nailed the issue Rachel, I will do some research into using the controllers instead.